# FTP UNIX to WINDOWS NT with Java

Tags: java, unix, ftp

Im using java to move a pdf file from Unix machine to other machine with Windows NT.

Im usin this code:

```
try
{
    client.connect(FTPHOST);
    client.user(FTPUSER);
    client.pass(FTPPASS);


    int reply = client.getReplyCode();
    System.out.println("Respuesta recibida de conexión FTP:" + reply);

    if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
    {
        System.out.println("Conectado Satisfactoriamente");    
    }else{
        System.out.println("Imposible conectarse al servidor");
    }           

    client.changeWorkingDirectory(FTPRUTA);

    //Activar que se envie cualquier tipo de archivo

    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
    buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
        ut.RUTA_OUTPUT + File.separator + rs.getString("X_MSISDN") + rs.getString("X_ID_ORDEN") + ficheroOut));//Ruta del archivo para enviar
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    client.storeFile(rs.getString("X_MSISDN") + rs.getString("X_ID_ORDEN") + ficheroOut, buffIn);//Ruta completa de alojamiento en el FTP

    buffIn.close(); //Cerrar envio de arcivos al FTP
    client.logout(); //Cerrar sesión
    client.disconnect();//Desconectarse del servidor
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Algo malo sucedió");
}
```

I tryed this code from unix to unix and works OK, but when I try to conect to the Windows machine the FTP give me Error 530

Can anyone help me please??

Thanks and regards

Comment: Looks like a password problem. Have you special characters in your password? if yes can you try to use only ascii char?

Comment: The password only contains letters and numbers y don't use special characters

Comment: Ok Now works OK. The problem was my user have a Slash "example/user" and in the windows machine change this slash to esc character, then I put a doble slash 'example//user' and now it's running OK. –